# Bootstrap navbar toggler icon (hamburger) size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just wondering if there is any way to resize Bootstrap's navbar toggler icon?

I'm using the `.navbar-dark` theme as a template, here are the dimensions:

```
.navbar-dark {
  background-color: #111 !important;
}

.navbar {
  background-image: url("/images/Harris_Logo_Small2.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 3px;  
}

.navbar-nav {
  background-color: #111111;
  border-color: #111111;
}
```

And here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ff0000;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

button.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

button.navbar-toggler .icon {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
  background-color: #111;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 20px !important;
}
```

As you can (hopefully) see, the toggler icon is far too large for the dimensions I've chosen for the navbar height.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide us with some live code example (maybe in JSFiddle) or some image in order to be able to see the "wrong" behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In bootstrap 3:**

You can override `.navbar-toggle .icon-bar` bootstrap class. check below snippet for reference.

```css
.navbar-dark {
  background-color: #111 !important;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
  width: 50px !important;
  height:3px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </
```

**In bootstrap 4:**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggler-icon{
  padding: 30px !important;
}
```

**Note:** In bootstrap 4 you cannot increase height/width independently. It will be affecting both `height` and `width` when using `padding`.

Comment: I was definitely building it with Bootstrap4, and I think that's where I was running into some problems.  Apparently the documentation isn't complete just yet, and I was trying to style it in accordance to BS3 documentation, which obviously wasn't working.  I appreciate all the help, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4.1. You would most likely use the "navbar-toggler-icon" class.
In witch case, if you want to just resize the bars, you would just be resize the font-size of it:

```
.navbar-toggler-icon{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

If you want to resize the button around it, just target the "navbar-toggler" and mess with the padding/margins as you desire:

```
.navbar-toggler{
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just thinking, if you want a easy solution you could maybe use font awesome:

http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/

You can use the bars with just: `class="fa fa-bars fa-2"` where `fa-2` is the size of the bars.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 3px !important;
}
```

and

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    width: 14px !important;
    height: 1px;
}
```

you might add important to the padding and width to overwrite the boostrap css.
but this should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

U can change every width and height values specific values manually or give all of them % values and just change main navbar's height and width . If those values had % values you can just put them in a div.